# Using a variable sized range of data in mmult excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to re-use a formula I have working with a table with a standard data range. The range in question is auto-populated so it can't be turned in to a table.

The formula I have looks like this -

```
=LET(
staff, $Y$3:$AB$999,
employee, $Y$3:$Y$999,
role, $Z$3:$Z$999,
discipline, $AA$3:$AA$999,
endDate, $AB$3:$AB$999,
rowCt, MIN(IF(Y3:Y1000="",ROW(Y3:Y1000)-ROW(Y3)+1))-1,
roleSelection, $I$11,
employeeSelection, $I$8,
disciplineSelection, $I$14,
mmult_1, MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,rowCt,1,0),TRANSPOSE(endDate>TRANSPOSE(endDate))*(employee=TRANSPOSE(employee))*(1)),
mmult_2, MMULT((TRANSPOSE(employee)= employee)+0,SEQUENCE(rowCt,1,1,0)),
roleCondition, IF(ISBLANK(roleSelection),1,(role=roleSelection)),
employeeCondition, IF(ISBLANK(employeeSelection),1,( employee=employeeSelection)),
disciplineCondition, IF(ISBLANK(disciplineSelection),1,(discipline=disciplineSelection)),

AvailabilityCalc,FILTER(staff,roleCondition*employeeCondition*disciplineCondition*(TRANSPOSE(mmult_1)-mmult_2+1=0)),

IFERROR(SORT(INDEX(AvailabilityCalc,SEQUENCE(ROWS(AvailabilityCalc)),{1,2,3,4}),1),"")
)
```

The data currently lives in Y3:AB14 and if I switch this in to the above:

```
staff, $Y$3:$AB$14,
employee, $Y$3:$Y$14,
role, $Z$3:$Z$14,
discipline, $AA$3:$AA$14,
endDate, $AB$3:$AB$14,
```

for the various LET definitions it works fine. However, switching the 14 to 999 as above, no data is returned. Does anyone know what I'd need to change for this to work?

I also tried constructing the ranges based on the row amount defined by rowCt, to do this I shifted the rowCt to the first LET entry and switched in the following:

```
rowCt, MIN(IF(Y3:Y1000="",ROW(Y3:Y1000)-ROW(Y3)+1))-1,
staff, OFFSET($Y$3,0,0,28,rowCt),
employee, OFFSET($Y$3,0,0,25,rowCt),
role, OFFSET($Z$3,0,0,26,rowCt),
discipline, OFFSET($AA$3,0,0,27,rowCt),
endDate, OFFSET($AB$3,0,0,28,rowCt),
```

Unfortunately this gave me a circular ref.

Edit 1 :

Messed up my offsets, fixed with the following -

```
staff, OFFSET($Y$3,0,0,rowCt,4),
employee, OFFSET($Y$3,0,0,rowCt),
role, OFFSET($Z$3,0,0,rowCt),
discipline, OFFSET($AA$3,0,0,rowCt),
endDate, OFFSET($AB$3,0,0,rowCt),
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data and explain the end goal of the use of the calculation?

Comment: I don't understand your variable *rowCt*. Clearly if this is not of the same dimensions as the other variables then `MMULT` will fail. For example, if *endDate* and *employee* are set to `$AB$3:$AB$10` and `$Y$3:$Y$10` respectively, then `TRANSPOSE(endDate>TRANSPOSE(endDate))*(employee=TRANSPOSE(employee))` will comprise an 8x8 matrix. Consequently, if *rowCt* is not also equal to 8, then `MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,rowCt,1,0),TRANSPOSE(endDate>TRANSPOSE(endDate))*(employee=TRANSPOSE(employee))*(1))` will error. This error will be passed to your `IFERROR` clause and so a blank will result.

Comment: I assume, you are over thinking your problem. Simply show your input data and then desired output. There may be simple solution than you think.

Comment: I seem to recognize this LET function ;)  As Jos pointed out, something has gone horribly wrong here:  `rowCt, MIN(IF(Y3:Y1000="",ROW(Y3:Y1000)-ROW(Y3)+1))-1`.  This is almost certainly where things went off course.  Can you tell us in a comment the plain-language description of what you want rowCt to be?  This is very different than the `rowCt, ROWS(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl),` you had before.

Comment: hey Max, It's giving me the number of rows in the dataset before there's a blank row. I added an edit to my question above as I believe I now have it working.